# angular route children only the first path component works. Help me

Tags: angularjs

when I run the program, only the first path is running, ie the first component. When I move, the first path is working again. What do I have to do to make it all work? As the picture shows, Navbar shows the component on the home page, but not the other components. I would be glad if you help.enter image description here

**App.Module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    RoleComponent,
    RoleAddComponent,
    RoleUpdateComponent,
    RoleAuthorizationComponent,
    RoleMenuComponent,
    RoleMenuUpdateComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [AlertifyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
 

**app-routing.module**  


const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent,
      },            
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [            
          {
            path: '',
            component: NavbarComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full',
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: SidebarComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full',
          },            
          {
            path: '',
            component: FooterComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule],
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {}  

      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0RMR.png
```

[enter image description here][1]`enter code here`
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwxUY.png

Comment: Please clearly explain what does "[enter image description here][1]enter code here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwxUY.png" mean. You may replace with the UI snapshot u have.

Answer (score 0):

**Why it is not working?**

Basically, in this case, it works fine. Position of angular routes matters.

So u have something like this, you are clicking the home button and your URL change to something like this (localhost.com/home), then the first route is match and you are redirected to NavbarCompoent, work is done so no more redirection to other components.

Read more https://angular.io/guide/router

**Solution:**

This is one of the many solutions:

1.
Create one more component with or without module for those 3 (Navbar, Sidebar, and Footer Components), style them as you want (use selectors in HTML).
Route for a home component should look like this:

```
 {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [            
          {
            path: '',
            component: **NEWCOMPOENNT**,
          },      
        ],
      },
```

2. 

Other solutions require using nested router outlets.